# MySQL ER_SPECIFIC_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR when getting slave status

Tags: mysql

I'm often (but not always) getting ER_SPECIFIC_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR error when running  SHOW SLAVE STATUS  with a user that does indeed have the proper access.  This is from a thread that monitors the slave.  When the thread starts up it checks and gets a valid response but usually after its been running for a while it starts getting ER_SPECIFIC_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR and when that starts it usually happens until the thread is restarted.

Does ER_SPECIFIC_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR have multiple meanings?  Is it trying to tell me to call SHOW SLAVE STATUS less?

*Note this thread is either in NodeJS or C++ depending on the process. Its not language or platform specific.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a bug in the installed version of the server. It was Maria actually.  Maria DB on Ubuntu 14.4.  5.5.54-MariaDB-1ubuntu0.14.04.1. The solution was to migrate to Oracle MySQL 5.7